# Why const Ref on non-const pointer is interpreted as const pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why `const PointerToNonConst& value` is understood as `A* const` for the code below:

```
using PointerToNonConst = A*; // or typedef A* PointerToNonConst;
const PointerToNonConst& value; // compiled and understood as `A* const`
```

I have expected it to be read-only pointer instead on constant pointer.

BTW here is a use-case, why you may meet this in your code:

```
class A
{
public:
    void callOnNonConstMethodIsValid()
    {
        // change the object here
    }
}

std::vector<A*> vect;

for (const auto& elem : vect)
{
    elem->callOnNonConstMethodIsValid(); // no error
}
```

Comment: Surely it is `A* const&`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typedef` and `using` are not like `#define`. It is not text replacement. When you make a type alias with `typedef` or `using`, that name is then treated as a single unit. When you apply `const` to it, it applies the type as a whole, at top level. You cannot apply it to inner components of that type.

Comment: Makes complete sense, but in this case I read `const NonConstPtr& value` as read-only reference on non-read-only pointer. So finally is it read-only or not? It is confusing. What is the right way to read it then?

Comment: @Narek: If you realize that writing `const` before the type is actually a special case in the grammar, and you should actually write it after the type, then you can read C and C++ types right to left. So I would write that as `NonConstPtr const& value`, and read it as *"value is a reference to a const NonConstPtr"*. But that name is pretty confusing. The reason it's confusing though is because of the name you gave the type:  `"NonConstPtr"`. A more accurate name would be `"PointerToNonConst"`

Comment: And then the declaration would look like this: `PointerToNonConst const& value`, and could be read as *"value is a reference to a const PointerToNonConst"*.

Comment: Changing the name in my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
using NonConstPtr = A*; // or typedef A* NonConstPtr;
```

The declaration

```
const NonConstPtr& value = <initializer>;
```

is equivalent to

```
A* const& value = <initializer>;
```

`value` is a reference to a `const` pointer to an object of type `A`.

It is not equivalent to:

```
const A*& value = <initializer>;
```

where `value` is a reference to a pointer to `const A`.

This is one of the cases where it makes more sense to use the `const` keyword after the type.

```
NonConstPtr const& value = <initializer>;
```

If you do that, it might make more sense why the first interpretation is correct.

Comment: It *always* makes more sense to put `const` after the type. The fact that you can even put it before is a special case in the grammar.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I agree. I prefer to put `const` after the type.

Comment: @RSahu I would accept your answer either if there was a way.

Comment: @Narek, no worries. What's more important is that you find answer(s) to your question.